# How to Setup NSClient++ to automatically send metrics to REST server

Tags: python, windows, monitoring, nagios, graphite

We'd like to deploy NSClient++ on some windows servers to collect and send in metrics to our central server.  This central server can talk in any protocol (e.g., graphite/carbon protocol) if need be, but we'd really like it to submit each metric in JSON format to a central webserver running a REST interface that can receive them and do further processing.

We want mostly performance metrics to flow in, once a minute.  We don't care about non-numeric data, but if that comes in, too, that'd be fine, we can parse it into an alarm console if we receive it.

I get that I can install nsclient++ with a downloadable MSI installer.  Configuring it is a thing, then, but how?   I even have read that I can have it send performance data to a graphite server, but how do I intercept that performance data and do the sending myself via a REST interface?

I can code anything in Python, if there's a way to get the data I'm trying to send into my python app, I can use urllib2 (or requests) to send it in.

Can someone point me to a how-to on this if there is one out there, or explain how this fits together?

Answer (score 1):

After `NSClient++` installation, just copy below configuration in `C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nsclient.ini`

```
[/modules]
CheckDisk = enabled
CheckExternalScripts = enabled
CheckHelpers = enabled
CheckNet = enabled
CheckSystem = enabled
GraphiteClient = enabled
Scheduler = enabled


[/settings/graphite/client]
channel = GRAPHITE
hostname=windows

[/settings/graphite/client/targets/default]
address = 192.168.202.128


[/settings/scheduler/schedules/default]
interval = 10s
report = all


[/settings/scheduler/schedules]
cpu=alias_cpu
mem=alias_mem
disk=alias_disk
service=alias_service
channel = GRAPHITE
```

With NSclient++ we can send metrics to Nagios with `NSCA` protocol or to Graphite server. So, in the config file we are defining `GRAPHITE` channel with some config (like `address`) and `scheduler`. The `scheduler` will collect the metrics and send it to `Channel`. According to above config, the `Graphite` is at `192.168.202.128`.

### Issue I was facing

But it is not picking the `hostname`. According to [graphite HTTP Doc](https://graphite-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), it should send metrics in formate like `<machine_name>.<Metric_Name> <Value>`,  but what I see is `<Metrics_name> <Value>`. If metrics are pushing from different machines, we can not differentiate.